# Show that $f$ is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $E$ be a nonvoid set,

$$F=\{ B \in \mathcal{P}(E) \ |\ B \subseteq A\}$$
and
$$G=\{B \in  \mathcal{P}(E) \ |\ A \subseteq B\}.$$

Let $f:\mathcal{P}(E) \to F \times G$ be given by
$$X \mapsto (A\cap X, A\cup X ).$$

How can one show that $f$ is bijective?

So I have to show that $f$ is injective and surjective.

But I didn't understand that function because it's about sets!

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: I assume $A$ is fixed?

Comment: @VikrantDesai fixed

Comment: @JohnMa yes you can

Comment: BTW, since you've asked a number of questions ($>30$) in the site already. I don't see why you cannot format the question properly. @user233658

Comment: @JohnMa it's my first functional questions

Comment: These are basic math notations $\{$, $\in$, $\to$. You should have seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$X=\bigl((A\cup X)\smallsetminus A\bigr)\cup(A\cap X)$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the objects $f$ operates on are sets is not a problem. Just show that

1. the map is well defined, that is, $A\cap X\in F$ and $A\cup X\in G$, for all $X\in\mathcal{P}(E)$;
2. the map is injective, that is, $f(X)=f(Y)$ implies $X=Y$;
3. the map is surjective, that is, for $C\in F$ and $D\in G$, there exists $X\in\mathcal{P}(E)$ such that $A\cap X=C$ and $A\cup X=D$.

The first verification is obvious. Suppose $f(X)=f(Y)$, that is,
$$
A\cap X=A\cap Y,\qquad A\cup X=A\cup Y
$$
Let $x\in X$; there are two cases: either $x\in A$ or $x\notin A$. In the first case $x\in A\cap X=A\cap Y$, so $x\in Y$. In the second case, $x\in A\cup X=A\cup Y$, so $x\in A\cup Y$; since $x\notin A$, we get $x\in Y$. Therefore $X\subseteq Y$. By symmetry, also $Y\subseteq X$. Hence $X=Y$ and the map $f$ is injective.

Try your hand with surjectivity. Hint: given $C\subseteq A$ and $D\supseteq A$, consider $X=C\cup(D\setminus A)$.